# Get property name when using @property decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

Let's take this piece of code.

```
class property_name(object):
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.property_name = function.__name__
        self.function = function

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.function(self)

class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    # @property
    @property_name
    def temperature(self):
        print(self.property_name)
        return 24.5

    # @property
    @property_name
    def time(self):
        print(self.property_name)
        return "12:45 am"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Test()
    print(t.temperature)
    print(t.time)
```

Now, so far I know, the property decorator doesn't has a way to get the name of the property as a string like `temperature` or `time`.

So, I decided to try to get the function name by writing the decorator `property_name`. Decorating the function with this decorator does exactly what I need. The decorator adds the attribute `property_name` to the class with the name of the function which has been called. So far everything works and is clear.

But, when I chain the `property` decorator, then I get troubles:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_func_name.py", line 28, in <module>
    t.temperature()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Debugging the code, I see that both methods `temperature` and `time` are `None`.

How can I chain my decorator to `property`? Is there a better solution for that problem?

Comment: May I ask why it matters? It seems obvious that the output would be `time` if you are inside `def time`. What are you really trying to solve here?

Comment: If you really want to print the name of the attribute you're accessing, you can still use `getattr` and access the attribute with a variable which contains a string that you can print.

Comment: As of Python 3.6, the descriptor protocol supports (via `__set_name__`) discovering the name to which a descriptor is assigned. I wonder if `property` will ever be updated to use that.

Comment: @DeepSpace It matters. Imagine you store all the properties inside a dictionary. In this case, the key of the dictionary MUST always match with the name of the function. If I would write the key (in this case the name of the function) manually, then I could potentially introduce some typo errors. That's why I prefer to get the name of the function like that.

Comment: Once you make `temperature` a property, you don't need to call it; `t.temperature` alone causes `print(self.property_name)` to be called, and the value of `t.temperature` is `None`. As a result, you are trying to call `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the value of the function you are calling in `property_name.__call__`:

```
class property_name(object):
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.property_name = function.__name__
        self.function = function

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.function(self)
```

Then

```
$ python3 tmp.py
temperature
24.5
time
12:45 am
```